# Locals Window Not Showing in Run & Debug Tab

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm pretty new to VsCode and am having a weird issue where my locals window in the Run & Debug panel isn't showing for some reason. I can run debug mode fine and pause on breakpoints, etc. and see my watchlist, callstack, and breakpoint windows but locals is just missing for some reason, and when I right click at the top of the panel to show the toggle options it shows "Watch", "Call Stack", and "Breakpoints" as you'd expect but locals doesn't appear there either. I've asked other team members more familiar with VsCode but they were unable to help me track it down. Another user was able to log onto the same PC under a different account and run VsCode and it showed properly so my best guess is there's some user setting I unwittingly disabled when I installed but I haven't found anything so far. The issue has even persisted across multiple reinstalls, even including different versions (currently on 1.80.1) Any help much appreciated! [Panel toggle options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3r3X.png) [Missing locals panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKED8.png)

See description in problem details.

Comment: Update, another user suggested a post for missing windows in VsCode which turned out to be very helpful, turned out my locals were hidden in the "secondary side bar" so found them by going to view > appearance > secondary side bar, once that was open was able to drag them back over to my main sidebar, thanks for the help!